# Finding problems in citrus payment integration in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, citrus-pay

I am working on integrating `CITRUS` payment in `IOS`.I am almost done with the integration and also able to make payment successfully.

But I am facing one issue here and that is when I am calling  the citrus page I load's the current page with my order but it look's page with some HTML tag's, please see the image :

[image]

And on this page when I click on `SUBMIT` button then my order get's completed successfully.

So if anybody have faced the same issue and knows any solution for this please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error. It is the test page showing that you need to host the page where response comes. So once you switch to the production keys, this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In India, RBI (Reserver Bank of India) Mandates that all card payments should go through two-factor authentication.This means the payer will be redirected to an ACS ( Access Control Server) Page where the payer is expected to enter an OTP/Password/ ATM Pin as the case may be.

Citrus Payments have simulated a test ACS Page in their sandbox environment which is shown in the screenshot you attached with the question.

Once you click submit button on this page, you will be redirected to a "return URL" passed in the incoming request.You are required to validate the response send by Citrus once the request arrives on this URL and display the same to the customer.